# How to add confirm email at checkout form in Magento 2.2.0

Tags: checkout, forms, magento2.2.0

I need to add confirm email field to the **checkout page**. I could not trace the file path - from where does it appear? Could anyone tell me the path for the checkout form?

Answer (score 1):

By Enabling template path hints in the admin , you can locate the  file path.

Front-End

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
>   Template     Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Admin

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled
>   Template Path Hints for Admin > Yes

Comment: I did so but got nothing

Comment: did you flush the cache?

Comment: I meant I did not get the path after enabled of path link

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml

Comment: I have tried for the given path but I didnot get any form there

Comment: go to vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml and see the xml files

Answer (score 0):

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/form/element/email.html